# Return the value of array from Array.prototype method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code.

```
Array.prototype.range = function(start, count) {
  this.push(start);
  if(this.length == count){
     return this;
  };
  this.range(start+1, count)
}
```

It's functional in that it modifies the array how I intend it to, but there's no return value.

```
test = new Array;
test.range(0,3);
console.log(test);
```

Will output [0,1,2], but

```
test = new Array;
console.log(test.range(0,3));
```

Gives me undefined.  Can someone explain to me why "return this;" in a prototyped method doesn't actually return the object?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what its supposed to do

Comment: (Unrelated) You're missing a semicolon after the last `this.range` call and the semicolon after the `if` block is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return from the initial call.

```
return this.range(start + 1, count);
```